# How to Exclude Child Element from jQuery Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am modifying an existing web page. I added a `<textarea>` to the page, but found that the Enter key doesn't work as expected.

After spending considerable time searching, I found the following:

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        return false;
});
```

I need to leave as much as much of the existing functionality in place as I can. But I need to disable this for my `<textarea>`. (It appears mine is the only `<textarea>` on the page.

But how can I do this? I thought about adding `.not('textarea')` to the selector above. But that doesn't work because the handler is on the form, which is not a textarea.

I can I exclude `<textarea>`s from the filter above?

Comment: use on() instead of keypress() and a :not(textarea) in the css arg

Comment: I don't understand this. The form is never a textarea, so how does adding :not(textarea) work?

Comment: Is the text area inside the form element?

Comment: on() adds events to the element and it's children, which you note includes a textarea.

Comment: @dandavis except if you use delegation, `.on` will do the same as the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xoxid/3/edit)**

You can simply target the inputs

```
$('form input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) e.preventDefault(); // Don't misuse return false
});
```

the textarea will go on with the enter key as usual

Depends on the use-case.

**If you want to be sure nothing brakes use:**

```
$('form *:not(textarea)').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) e.preventDefault();
});
```

where `*` targets every children, and `:not` selector excludes the desired one.

here's another example:

```
$('form *').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && this.tagName!=="TEXTAREA") e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: This assumes that no other elements within the form that are *not* inputs would be affected. That might very well be true.

Comment: @JonathanWood beside input, textarea and contenteditable... you have more elements that accept text key events??

Comment: <select>, <a>, <button>, etc

Comment: @dandavis can you please explain your comment?

Comment: the elements mentioned both use key events and have default  [enter] behaviors

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Is that a question? Thanks to your mention of `contenteditable`, it appears almost any element can accept text key events??

Comment: This appears to be the simplest fix. Although it doesn't logically eliminate any other element from being affected, it doesn't appear that any are in my case.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Welcome to the World of ASP.NET WebForm applications.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: for <A>, it's to navigate to the href, and for select it's to choose a selection (and fire onchange) after using the arrow keys to highlight an <option>

Comment: @dandavis if you put an `A` link inside your form is there ANY reason I should not be allowed to use enter on it? No. It'll not submit the form... it'll just follow the link. Also, if you have a `select` element you actually select a desired value using ARROW keys, not ENTER. ENTER key will not trigger anything AFAIK... BUTTON following the same logic, if used inside a FORM should do exactly what's supposed to do so actually keeping all that elements intact is a good thing. Prove me wrong please.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: as much as i like proving folks wrong, i'm not even sure what you're saying, much less if it's right or wrong. i never said anything about submitting the form, just that there's lots of elements beside input and textarea that use [enter] for various things. some behaviors, like arrow keys firing <select> onchange() depend on the browser. for example, firefox (accessibly) waits until [enter] to fire onchange when arrows are used to modify the visible selection, chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the if the target is the textarea :

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('textarea')) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: This isn't my preference but is an option. One thing I worried about was that the target would be the form, since that is the selector, instead of the textarea.

Comment: @JonathanWood It can't, the target is always the first element in the bubling phase. `currentTarget` will be the form.

Comment: This and dandavis answer are the same, but written differently.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: this code fires on textarea key events and requires custom code to ignore those presses, the on() version never fires at all on textarea events...

Comment: @dandavis Actually, that's false. Delegation bind an event on the form then bubble up the DOM to see if it match the selector. They are both, exactly the same. JavaScript doesn't have native delegation, jQuery simulate it just like my code does it.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: the difference is that you spin up a whole jq object to do "if($(e.target).is('textarea')) return;", per keypress, whereas when you use on(), jQuery does all that for you...

Comment: @dandavis jQuery do a lot of things behind your back, here check the test case : http://jsperf.com/delegation-vs-manual-check

Comment: how can you possibly benchmark an event handler like that by clicking it once? yeah, delegation costs more to build, but it's supposed to save a lot of work each invocation, and it's shorter to code. also consider that on() is new and suggested over older specific handlers, so it's a good idea to go on() even if the other implications were a wash.

Comment: @dandavis 1) the benchmark in the fiddle only catch the click event. 2) No matter how much time you click, it will be the same speed (http://jsfiddle.net/3JN2C/2/) Some variation, sometime slower, sometime faster. 3) I know that `.on`is new, it replaced `.bind()` but you **shouldn't** always use delegation. Yes you should always use `.on` though. 4) I'm not saying your answer is bad, I upvoted yours. I'm saying they are the same. Delegation is sorta doing the same as I am doing here.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: i agree they accomplish the same thing. furthermore, if you need to block certain keys from certain tags, this is the way to go, but for just blocking one key on one tag, on() works well.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use on(), so you don't need to do any extra element comparing inside the event handler:

```
$('form').on("keypress", ":not(textarea)", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        return false;
});
```

you use on() to watch the form, and the css selector to avoid textareas.
to easily tweak later, you can blacklist other elements by tagname or class using more :not() operators sperated by commas. plus, on() is now recommended over the older single-purpose handlers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter inside your function like this

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea')
        return false;
});
```